# Android Studio: Preview rendering not appearing for all my XML files

Tags: xml, android-studio, render, preview

Since I've added the glide dependencies into my gradle folder, all my preview renders have not been showing up. I've tried invalidating, rebuilding, syncing and even deleting the .ideas files. I removed the added glide dependencies as well. However, still no success. Please help, thank you!!!

some of the errors:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:854)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:603)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:50)
    at android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.build(StaticLayout.java:425)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:8385)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:8204)
    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8586)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:592)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:345)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

2.

```
 java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 16
    at android.text.StaticLayout.generate(StaticLayout.java:854)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:603)
    at android.text.StaticLayout.<init>(StaticLayout.java:50)
    at android.text.StaticLayout$Builder.build(StaticLayout.java:425)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeSingleLayout(TextView.java:8385)
    at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:8204)
    at android.widget.TextView.onMeasure(TextView.java:8586)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.onMeasure_Original(AppCompatTextView.java:501)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.onMeasure(AppCompatTextView.java)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1535)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1187)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:706)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6749)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
    at android.view.View.measure_Original(View.java:23169)
    at android.view.View_Delegate.measure(View_Delegate.java:80)
    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:23133)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.measureView(RenderSessionImpl.java:592)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:345)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:386)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:590)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

3. My styles android:windowFullScreen cannot be resolved as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still ran into some issues with the rendering, especially those that use androidx functions. However, I did manage to view most of my renders after reinstalling android studio. Hopefully, that is rather helpful to those who need it!

Answer (score -2):

I encounter the same java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error and tried to run File > Invalidate Caches, Restart. It didn't work for me.

My layout preview wont show because I had an error in the layout file. To fix this, **try commenting out each of the component in the layout XML file one by one**. Keep trying till you find out which component is causing this error.

It is likely that your error is caused by an EditView component or other text related components.